# UICollectionView: how to detect when scrolling has stopped

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, uicollectionview

I'm using a `UICollectionView` to scroll through a set of thumbnails quickly. Once scrolling ends, I'd like to display a larger hi-res version of the current thumbnail.

How can I detect when the user has completed scrolling? I do implement `didEndDisplayingCell`, but that only tells me when a particular cell has scrolled off; it doesn't tell me when the scroll motion actually completes.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0) @interface UICollectionView : UIScrollView
```

`UICollectionView` is a subclass of `UIScrollView`. So if you have set the delegate and implemented `UIScrollViewDelegate`, you should be able to detect this the same way as `UIScrollView`.

For eg:-

**Objective-C:**

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate;
```

**Swift:**

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)
func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool)
```

As per [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:), the above method should tell when the scroll view has ended decelerating the scrolling movement. Note that `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` would not be called in some cases as mentioned in comments.

Comment: Brilliant. You don't know how much nasty code this saved me. I was trying to monitor it using the shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange callback in my UICollectionViewFlowLayout. What a n00b.

Comment: Please see D6mi's note below about scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation. scrollViewDidEndDecelerating does not get called for programmatic scrolling.

Comment: Indeed, I don't understand why the current answer is the accepted one, it does not work `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating ` is not called but like D6mi said, `scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation` is called

Comment: This answer is not complete.

Comment: Brilliant answer. @Nathanael,  the answer is complete since he pointed out that UICollectionView is a subclass of UIScrollView and also quoted an eg:- delegate method. Rest of the answers just took this answer and added other delegate methods to it. Ideally rest should be just a comment on this answer. The keypart is collectionview is just a scrollview, rest can be figured out.

Answer (score 61):

Just to cover your bases you should implement both these UIScrollViewDelegate methods.
In some cases there may not be a deceleration (and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` would not be called), for e.g., the page is fully scrolled in place. In those case do your update right there in `scrollViewDidEndDragging`.

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{
  if (!decelerate) {
    [self updateStuff];
  }
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
  [self updateStuff];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this! This should be the accepted answer b/c OP asked "scrolling has stopped" -- without both methods in place the user can easily scroll the collection view down and release finger without flicking and `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` will NOT get called, `scrollViewDidEndDragging` does. Thank you for posting this answer.

Answer (score 36):

An important fact to note here.

This method gets called on User initiated scrolls (i.e a Pan gesture):

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView;`

or in **Swift**:

`func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

On the other hand, this one gets called on all manually (programatically) initiated scrolls (like `scrollRectToVisible` or `scrollToItemAtIndexPath`):

`- (void)scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

or in **Swift**:

`func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)`

Answer (score 14):

Swift 3 version of Abey M and D6mi 's answers:

When scroll is caused by user action

```
public func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
    if (!decelerate) {
        //cause by user
        print("SCROLL scrollViewDidEndDragging")
    }
}

public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //caused by user
    print("SCROLL scrollViewDidEndDecelerating")
}
```

When scroll is caused by code action (programmatically): (like "scrollRectToVisible" or "scrollToItemAtIndexPath")

```
public func scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    //caused by code
    print("SCROLL scrollViewDidEndScrollingAnimation")
}
```

Notes:

- Put these functions in your UIScrollViewDelegate or UICollectionViewDelegate delegate.
- if you don't have a separate delegate, make your current class extend a UIScrollViewDelegate op top of your class file

.

```
open class MyClass: NSObject , UICollectionViewDelegate
```

and somewhere in your viewWillAppear make the class its own delegate

```
override open func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    // ...
    self.myScrollView.delegate = self
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift 3 version:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use the visible indexpath:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [self scrollingFinish];
}
- (void)scrollingFinish {


    if([self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElementsOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]){
        NSIndexPath *firstVisibleIndexPath = [[self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleSupplementaryElementsOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader] firstObject];
        [self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:firstVisibleIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionTop animated:YES];
        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get your collection view index and Dont forget to import `UISCrollViewDelegate` in your class

```swift
public func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let xPoint = scrollView.contentOffset.x + scrollView.frame.width / 2
    let yPoint = scrollView.frame.height / 2
    let center = CGPoint(x: xPoint, y: yPoint)
    if let ip = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: center) {
        pageIndex = ip.row
    }
    print(">>>>>>>>>\(pageIndex)")
}
```