# How to check in UICollectionViewFlowLayout that in which direction the uicollectionview is scrolling? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I knew how to check the direction using scroll view delegate methods. But unfortunately, I have a situation where I have to do the same in UICollectionViewFlowLayout but I can't access with scroll view delegate methods.
I tried the ways to check(inside custom layout) in which direction collection view is scrolling, but there was no luck. Please help me in this case.

Further more details:
I want to check the condition inside the custom layout. If the scroll direction is vertical. I want to find is it going top or bottom.

Comment: I think for that you need to access delegate method of `ScrollView`, Can you please care to explain more, why you are not using scrollViewdelegate? May be you can create your own custom delegate and implement with your custom flowlayout and called its method from scrollView delegate method to know the current scrolling direction in flowlayout

Comment: if I want to use scrollviewdelegate. I have to add a scrollview inside collectionviewlayout. To add that whenever I do something like inside layout as collection.addSubView(scrollView) // it crashes, I assume colllectionview is not ready since it is inside the layout. But I might be wrong.

Comment: Why you are adding scrollview in collectionView collectionView is already sub class of ScrollView check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/14904948/6433023

Comment: As I said I am actually wanted to check inside the custom uicollectionview flow layout. The reference points me to uicollectionview :)

Comment: Ok but you can try this way, create your one protocol and implement with your custom flowlayout and called its method from scrollView delegate method to know the current scrolling direction in flowlayout

Comment: where will be this scrollviewdelegate methods exists? Do I need to subclass UICollectionView and implement the scrollviewdelegate methods and call the protocol method or do I need to do it from ViewController's delegate method? @NiravD

Comment: @NiravD I think there will be a default method just like tableview scolling delegate method. Is there any method for collectionview scoll delegate?

Comment: In ViewController where you are having collectionViewDatasource method along with  it add scrollView's method it will call automatically

Comment: @JeckyModi what do you mean by "tableview scrolling delegate method"?

Comment: @JeckyModi UITableView and UICollectionView are inherited from UIScrollView :)

Comment: I mean we have a default scoll delegate method like scrollViewDidScroll, So is this method will work for collectioview also @NiravD ?

Comment: @NiravD it worked. But is it good practice to do it from VC? I mean my whole purpose is to do something in layout. So can't I do the same in custom UICollectionView and use this custom UICollectionView inside the custom layout. Just a thought. I am bit noob here :)

Comment: @JeckyModi obviously its work for both tableView and collectionView

Comment: @coolly Don't you have added collectionView delegate and datasource method in viewController. Don't know if there is any direct way with flow layout also can I post my suggestion as solution?

Comment: well i didnt implement fully but I was such a noob didnt think of your way. Well, yes please do that. :) I can mark it as answer :)

Comment: @NiravD yeah I do have but it's bit hard to convey to fellow developers when someone wants to use this custom layout and want's to find the direction. All I have to do is implement the scrollview delegate method, that is bit weird. If something like this I can do under custom uicollectionview. I will try this way.

Comment: @coolly Then will wait for something like that, if you don't get solution like that then I will post my comment as answer

Comment: protocol GetDirection {
     func scrollViewDirectionInLayout(scrollView: UIScrollView)
}

class CustomLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, GetDirection {


    func scrollViewDirectionInLayout(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
       //cal to find the direction
    }

}

class VC: UIViewController {


   func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView){

        if collectionView = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? CustomLayout {
             collectionView.collectionViewLayout.scrollViewDirectionInLayout(scrollView)
        }
   }
} @NiravD I came up with this. What say?

Comment: Yes that also possible by casting collectionViewLayout to cutomlayout and call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one method with your `CustomFlowLayout` and with `scrollViewDidScroll` method call it.

```
class CustomFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {

    var currentScrollDirection = ""

    func currentScroll(direction: String) {
        currentScrollDirection = direction
    }
}
```

Now implement `scrollViewDidScroll` method with your `ViewController` and call the `currentScroll` method with `CustomFlowLayout`.

```
var lastContentOffset = CGPoint.zero
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
    var scrollDirection = (currentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset.y) ? "Down" : "Up"
    if let flowLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? CustomFlowLayout {
        flowLayout.currentScroll(direction: scrollDirection) 
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = currentOffset
}
```

Comment: my question might not be clear may be. I will update it. I want to check the condition inside the custom layout. Also, If the scroll direction is .vertical. I want to find is it going top or bottom.

Comment: @coolly I think for that you need to access delegate method of `ScrollView` Can you please care to explain why you are not using scrollView Delegate?

Comment: @coolly Check one edited answer without the need of `protocol`

Answer (score 3):

Without any protocols or without `UIScrollViewDelegate`. You can use this in your custom UICollectionViewFlow.

Enum for better code

```
enum ScrollDirection {
    case left
    case right
}
```

And then the function itself which you can use anytime

```
func getScrollDirection() -> ScrollDirection? {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }

    let scrollVelocity = collectionView.panGestureRecognizer.velocity(in: collectionView.superview)
    if (scrollVelocity.x > 0.0) {
        return .right
    } else if (scrollVelocity.x < 0.0) {
        return .left
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The function may return nil in some cases so be sure to check it if needed

Use like this

```
if getScrollDirection() == .left
```